# Importing content from EE1 into an existing EE2 website

Tags: ee2, ee1, export, datagrab

We have a use case where we need to import content from an EE1 website to an EE2 website (with existing content). I'm guessing it has to be a custom scripting job, but asking here in case someone knows a smart way of doing this.

One idea I guess is to use DataGrab for the import, but we'd still need to do an export from EE1 in XML (or another format which can be read by DataGrab).

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to export your weblog entries, you can use this add-on for EE1:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/weblog-entries-exporter

> This is a module for EE1; it basically allows CSV/XML export of weblog entries (if you choose XML it also deserializes the data in serialized fields).

Comment: nice, that was quick ;-) - thanks -- didn't know about that one, will have a look. Guessing there will be issues with images etc. but it looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use a custom script to export data into XML files by channel, doing any manipulation of image paths, etc on that side.

Than I use DataGrab to import everything.

One tip, make sure you export and import an ID field from your old system, so you can update an import later without deleting all the entries if you realize something didn't export correctly.

Comment: Well we do similar but just create XML templates. As mentioned, all data manipulation is done on the template side and then we point DataGrab directly at the XML templates to import.

Comment: That's pretty cool. How do you handle outputting file upload destination variables? Don't they get parsed out?

Comment: We use a string replacement method - in EE1 you can use something like [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace/docs)